# Phoneauthprovider is not a function firebase react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Hi everybody im making a app using react-native and fire base im have this initial config at firebase config :

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
// Firebase Config
// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.authDomain,
  projectId: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.appId
};

let Firebase

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  console.log('hello world')
  Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default Firebase;
```

And im triyng to call this method:

```js
  const loginUser = async() => {
    switch(loginType){
      case 0:
      break;
      case 1:
        if (typeof(verificationId) == 'string') { 
          setLoading(true)
          try {
            const credential = new Firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId,
              verificationCode
            );
            await Firebase.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
            showMessage({ text: 'Phone authentication successful ' }); 
          } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false)
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: 'red' });
          }
        } else {
          try {
              const phoneProvider = Firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
              const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,
                recaptchaVerifier.current
              );
              setVerificationId(verificationId);
              showMessage({
                text: 'Verification code has been sent to your phone.',
              });
          } catch (err) {
              showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: 'red' });
          }
        }
      break;
    }
  }
```

When im try to call my 'phone Login method' react-native show me this message:
[image]

im use this guide for how to configure the enviroment:
https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-integrate-firebase-authentication-with-an-expo-app

but using phone verification with recaptcha im not found the problem i believe the problem its in my implementation but in not found nothing

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

You're importing your own `Firebase` object, which is an instance of `FirebaseApp`. The `PhoneAuthProvider` class is not defined on `FirebaseApp`, but rather is in the (static) `firebase.auth` namespace.

So you either need to also import the regular Firebase Auth SDK into your code, instead of just your own `Firebase object, or you can attach the` firebase.auth`namespace to your`Firebase` object and use it from there with:

```
...
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  console.log('hello world')
  Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  Firebase.auth = firebase.auth;
}

export default Firebase;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to implement phone auth using firebase and I personally had success doing that using this:

```
async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    //1. Have the user input thei phone number into a TextInput and pass it to this function
    //2. Have a confirm useState to make sure the verification code was sent successfully by firebase
    //3. Check for the confirm state in the main component and show the user another TextInput to enter the verification code if confirm has a value
    await firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
        .then(confirmation => {
            setConfirm(confirmation)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            Alert.alert('Error sending verification code to this phone number')
        })
}

async function confirmCode(code) {
    //1. Have the code the user entered through the TextInput pass through here and call the below function
    try {
        let validation = await confirm?.confirm(code)
        if (validation) console.log('correct code.')
    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Invalid code.')
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method. There is no error but phone cannot be verified. Can you share your imports for the component?